# Using Qt3D in a widget application

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt3d

I'm planning to add an interactive 3D model to my application. 3D objects of model should be rotated and moved within C++ code. The whole model is also subject to change during calculations. It also should be a widget in the main window (not a separate window). Objects are in STEP format, but we can convert them to any other needed format if needed.

There are many APIs / Tools / Libraries which I can't find which one is suitable for my application. I'm looking for suggestions or a start point.

**Platform**: Linux/Windows 
**Toolchain**: C++ / Qt 4 and 5 / OpenGL

Answer (score 3):

When using version 5, this can serve you to start. [Loading 3D Model](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Loading-a-3D-Model)

Also recomend use [Blender](http://www.blender.com) to create and export in many formats.
Another option is download models in www.turbosquid.com (there are free and paid) is faster when you have no experience in modeling